# CTRL+A resets Paragraph Margins in Rich Text Box/Flow Document

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml

```xml
<RichTextBox x:Name="TextEntry">
    <FlowDocument>
        <Paragraph Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
    </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

This is a basic layout of my current XAML. When I first launch my application, it works fine. However, after pressing CTRL+A, the margins seem to reset & one press to `Enter` seems to add two new lines to the Paragraph.

Is there some way I should counter this behavior? Or perhaps I'm going about changing the margin incorrectly?

I've tried adding implementations in C# to override the default behavior of CTRL+A and pre-maturely register the event as handled to prevent any weird manipulation to go on in the background, alas that has not gotten me anywhere.

Comment: Just a guess, but isn't Paragraph the contents of your control, and thus changed by your input? What if you set margin property for the parent element (FlowDocument) and/or decrease padding for RitchTextBox instead?

Comment: @svin83 Paragraph doesn't change on input, only when CTRL+A is pressed. It's weird. But sadly FlowDocument doesn't have a Margin property, and the RTB's margin shouldn't be fiddled with to stay within it's height/width.

Comment: RTB Padding, not margin.

Comment: @svin83 Sadly, no. No sauce. I wonder if CTRL+A (then yet unrelated) pressing Backspace ends up deleting the Paragraph & storing raw text in the FlowDocument &or creating a new boilerplate Paragraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem.

CTRL+A+BACKSPACE was deleting the *entire* Paragraph object, which was statically styled. Upon new input, raw text just got thrown into a brand new Paragraph. Here's a solution:

```xml
<RichTextBox>
    <RichTextBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Paragraph}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
        </Style>
    </RichTextBox.Resources>
    <FlowDocument>
        <Paragraph Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
    </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```